# Prestashop $product->save() won't always save

Tags: php, caching, prestashop, product

I'm sending some data via cURL to PS SitemapController i overwrote :

With that data i proceed in a custom function like that :

```
$product = new Product($_POST['id']);
$product->price = $_POST['price'];
$product->wholesale_price = $_POST['wholesale_price'];
$product->unity = $_POST['unity'];
$product->save();
```

Then my problem happens : sometimes it will save my changes to the product, sometimes not.

To be sure i was always sending the data to the controller, i'm creating a log.txt file right before the $product->save() line, with data written in there. I checked, and my wordpress plugin is systematically sending the data to the controller and the function. The problem really seems to appear on save() function because a fputs right after product->save() won't do anything (when it is not saved btw).

Hopefully someone will know more about this and be a light on my path!

Comment: If code after `save()` doesn't work then `save()` method is throwing an exception.Wrap the save method in a try catch block and log the exception.

Comment: Try to use $product->add() if !$product->id or $product->update() if product exists. If the problem will be the same then you need to dig deeper. And turn on debug mode to get what occurs the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TheDrot and Alexander Grosul, for giving me paths to resolve my problem.

I replaced my save() action by the update() action and wrapped the whole thing with try catch block, logged the thrown exception, and turned PS on debug mode.

After doing some maths to calculate price with taxes, in certain cases, the result was a long float and prestashop couldn't accept that as a product price. The exception thrown was 'price not valid'. So i solved it with round() and everything works well now, updating product each time. I was so unsure about the prestashop cache system i didn't think of it... Thanks again ;)